# How to select number of k in cross validation for fbprophet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-prophet

I have data in pandas DataFrame and have been trying to train the model fbprophet. During the `cross validation` stage I am unable to select number of `k` like you can in sklearn. Meaning k=5, k=50 folds...etc. Is there an option here or way to pass that? I couldn't find this information in the fbprophet documentation. It seems like it is selecting number of fold in the image below to 71? I am not sure how it is selecting that. How can I specify this?

[image]
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)

```
# Model Evaluation - RMSE and MAE
df_cv = cross_validation(m, initial='200 days', period='180 days', horizon = '30 days')
pm = performance_metrics(df_cv)
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial paremeter specifies the amount of data to hold out for the first fold and the period parameter specifies the number of days to include in each fold, this is auto-calculated by fbprophet library as there's no way to tune this parameter, perhaps you can only tweak around with it to fit the initial/period parameters to fit your requirements.

cross-validation to assess prediction performance on a horizon of 365 days, starting with 730 days of training data in the first cutoff and then making predictions every 180 days. On this 8 year time series, this corresponds to 11 total forecasts.

```
# Python
from prophet.diagnostics import cross_validation
df_cv = cross_validation(m, initial='730 days', period='180 days', horizon = '365 days')
```

Source:
You can read and study the documentation example of that in here:
https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/diagnostics.html#cross-validation